# Solve $y(1+xy)dx + x(1+xy+x^2y^2)dy = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I came across this question in of my textbook, I tried solving it but i got stuck here. 
Please help me complete solving it.

My approach:
For given eq I've tried to check if it's a exact differential equation but it was not. I got $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \ne \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}$

Then I try to reduce the given eq to exact differential equation by finding Integrating Factor (I.F).

**I.F** = $\frac{1}{Mx - Ny}$

Then I multiplied I.F with given equation to convert it into exact differential equation. After, I tried to check the condition $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} = \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}$ but I got $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \ne \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}$.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: WA says this here $$\text{Solve}\left[\frac{-\frac{1}{2
   x^2}-\frac{y(x)}{x}}{y(x)^2}+\log
   (y(x))=c_1,y(x)\right]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y(1+xy)dx + x(1+xy+x^2y^2)dy = 0\tag1$$
Comparing $(1)$ with $~Mdx+Ndy=0~$, we have
$$M=y(1+xy)\qquad\text{and}\qquad N=x(1+xy+x^2y^2)$$ 
showing that $(1)$ is of the form $$f_1(xy)~y~dx+f_2(xy)~x~dy=0~.$$
Again $~Mx-Ny=xy(1+xy)-xy(1+xy+x^2y^2)=-x^3y^3\ne 0~$.

Hence the integrating factor (I.F.) is $~\dfrac{1}{Mx-Ny}=-\dfrac{1}{x^3y^3}~$.

Multiplying both side of $(1)$ by I.F. we have 
$$\dfrac{1}{x^3y^2}(1+xy)dx + \dfrac{1}{x^2y^3}(1+xy+x^2y^2)dy = 0$$
$$\left[\dfrac{1}{x^3y^2}+\dfrac{1}{x^2y}\right]dx + \left[\dfrac{1}{x^2y^3}+\dfrac{1}{xy^2}+\dfrac{1}{y}\right]dy = 0$$
$$d\left(-\dfrac{1}{2x^{2}y^{2}}-\dfrac1{xy}+\ln y\right) = 0$$
Integrating we have
$$-\dfrac{1}{2x^{2}y^{2}}-\dfrac1{xy}+\ln y=c$$where $~c~$ is integrating constant.

Comment: thank you. It was a small mistake from my part.

Comment: Yes, during the calculation of $~Mx-Ny~$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to integrate the DE:
$$y(1+xy)dx + x(1+xy+x^2y^2)dy = 0$$
$$(1+xy)(ydx+xdy) + x^3y^2dy = 0$$
$$(1+xy)dxy+ x^3y^2 dy= 0$$
Divide by $(xy)^3$
$$\frac {(1+xy)dxy}{(xy)^3}+ \frac {dy}{y}= 0$$
Integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple by $x^ay^b$ so $Mdx+Ndy=0$ with$$M:=x^ay^{b+1}+x^{a+1}y^{b+2},\,N:=x^{a+1}y^b+x^{a+2}y^{b+1}+x^{a+3}y^{b+2}.$$We choose $a,\,b$ to achieve$$\begin{align}0&=\partial_yM-\partial_xN\\&=(b+1)x^ay^b+(b+2)x^{a+1}y^{b+1}\\&-(a+1)x^ay^b-(a+2)x^{a+1}y^{b+1}-(a+3)x^{a+2}y^{b+2}\\&=x^ay^b((b-a)(1+xy)-(a+3)(xy)^2)\\\implies a=b&=-3.\end{align}$$So$$\begin{align}0&=Mdx+Ndy\\&=(x^{-3}y^{-2}+x^{-2}y^{-1})dx+(x^{-2}y^{-3}+x^{-1}y^{-2}+y^{-1})dy\\&=df,\\f&:=-\frac12x^{-2}y^{-2}-x^{-1}y^{-1}+\ln y.\end{align}$$