# What is my mistake in solving $y(1+xy)dx + x(1+xy+x^2y^2)dy = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have $$y(1+xy)dx + x(1+xy+x^2y^2)dy = 0$$

This equation has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478463/solve-y1xydx-x1xyx2y2dy-0?rq=1) and there are sevaral answers to it. But I'm wondering what is my mistake in solving it. Here is my approach:

Taking $u=xy$ we have,
$$du+yu\;dx+x(u^2+u)dy=0$$Dividing both sides by $u$,
$$\frac{du}u+du+xu\;dy=0$$

$$(1+\frac1u)du+x^2y\;dy=0$$
Hence the solution is
$$xy+\ln|xy|+\frac{x^2y^2}2=C$$
But the correct answer according to the question I'be linked is $-\dfrac{1}{2x^{2}y^{2}}-\dfrac1{xy}+\ln y=c$. What is the mistake in my approach?

Comment: When you integrate $x^{2}ydy$ you are treating $x$ as  constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ cannot be considered a constant as mentioned in comments. From the point where you got to,

$ \displaystyle \frac{du}u+du+xu\;dy=0$, you should substitute $x = \dfrac u y$

So we get, $ \displaystyle \frac{du}u + du + \frac{u^2}{y}\;dy=0$

or, $ \displaystyle \frac{du}{u^3} + \frac{du}{u^2} + \frac{dy}{y} = 0$

Now integrating and substituting $u$  back with $xy$ should give the correct answer.